# Ruby C API macros such as INT2NUM() return/store different numbers than expected

Tags: c, ruby, ffi

Currently I am using the Ruby C API and I am having trouble defining global Ruby variables.

Ruby values are stored in C as VALUE, or an `unsigned long`. The Ruby version I am using is v2.6.0p0, and I've tried using macros such as INT2NUM(), DBL2NUM() and INT2FIX() and the inputted number is always stored like so:

value * 2 + 1 -- if it's a whole number

value * 2     -- if it's a floating point number/double

Here is what I have:

```
#include <Ruby/ruby.h>

int main() {
    ruby_init();

    /* Test with no Ruby variables, just to see what it outputs 
       using INT2NUM() */
    VALUE x = INT2NUM(3);
    printf("%lu", x);

    /* Test storing y in a Ruby variable, then calling it using
       INT2FIX() */
    VALUE y = INT2FIX(4.5);
    rb_gv_set("$y", y);
    printf("%lu", rb_gv_get("$y"));

    /* Test storing z in a Ruby variable then calling it using 
       DBL2NUM() */
    VALUE z = DBL2NUM(6);
    rb_gv_set("$z", z);
    printf("%lu", rb_gv_get("$z"));

    ruby_cleanup(0);
    return 0;
}
```

For the first test, the output should be `3`, but it is printed out as `7` and the second test the output should be `4.5`, but it is printed out as `9`. The last test should be printed out as `6` but it prints out as `54043195528445954`, presumably the address where it's stored.

Comment: `INT2NUM` and other conversion macros return their argument encoded. If you want to use `printf` to print the original value then you need to convert it back with `NUM2INT`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about converting it back from a Ruby VALUE.